# How to mock datetime.datetime.now() to unittest timeout case?

Tags: python

Now I have a function which use `datetime.datetime.now()` to calculate time difference.

```
import datetime

TIMEOUT = datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)

def test():
  start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
  while datetime.datetime.now() - start_time < TIMEOUT:
    if do_something_succeed():
      return True
  return False
```

If I want to unittest the timeout case, I have to wait for 5 minutes.

If I mock `datetime.datetime.now()`, I'll get `TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'datetime.datetime'`.

How can I do to mock them to quickly do the timeout case?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/freezegun/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mock `datetime.datetime` itself.

```py
datetime = mock.Mock()
datetime.now = ...  # function or class that makes the magic happen

@mock.patch('mod.datetime', datetime)
def test_func():
  assert not test()
```

Comment: It might be easier in this case to just mock `TIMEOUT` instead.